# 2003 Mini Cooper S headlight not working

Tags: headlight, wiring, fuse, mini-cooper

I have a 2003 Mini Cooper S, the main near side headlight is not working. The rest of the lights on the near side work.

I have changed the bulb, and I have swapped the ballast over with the offside ballast, but still does not work.
Also the ballast from the near side does not work in the offside.

So I have determined that I have a faulty ballast for the near side, but also there is still further issues. Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: Have you checked the fuses?

Comment: HandyHowie, I checked the fuses and they looked fine. 
Hey, and update to this. I have removed the offside headlight and plugged it into the near side headlight wiring loom, and it works. So it appears the be the near side headlight unit. 
Does anyone know if fixing the wires in the headlight unit is easy, or is it better to buy a new or working used complete unit? Thanks